# join 2 objects with the same field name in vue.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, join

I'm trying to join 2 object by key, with 2 fields with the same name in these objects, but with different values.

```
var players = [{ id : 'a', name : "player1",team:1},{ id : 'b', name : "player2",team:1}, { id : 'c', name : "player3",team:2}]
var teams = [{ id : 1, name : "LA"}, {id : 2, name: "IL"}]
```

I want to be able to end up with something like:

```
var mergedList = [{ id : 'a', name : "player1",team.id:1, team.name: "LA"},
          { id : 'b', name : "player2",team__id:1, team_name: "LA"},
          { id : 'c', name : "player3",team__id:2, team_name: "US"}]
```

Here is what I tried so far:

```
const mergedList = players.map((player) => ({
        ...player,
        ...teams.find((team) => team__id === player_team),
      }));
```

But the name field from players is replaced by the name filed from teams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set new property keys for the fields from `teams`. And remember that the key is not allowed to include the `.`

```js
const mergedList = players.map((player) => {
    const team = teams.find((team) => team.id === player.team);
    return {
        ...player,
        team_id: team?.id,
        team_name: team?.name,
    }
});
```

Comment: can I make in one line the whole team filed names be "team_filedname" instead of stating them directly?

Comment: @David there is no way to do it. You can't spread object and rename its keys in one line

Answer (score 0):

The name is getting replaced because both `Player` and `Team` objects have a `name` property and the solution overwrites the `name` while combining the objects.

Since you want to access `team` object's `id` and `name` using `team.id` and `team.name` respectively, one suitable solution could be to have the team object inside the player object, something like :

```js
var players = [{ id : 'a', name : "player1",team:1},{ id : 'b', name : "player2",team:1}, { id : 'c', name : "player3",team:2}]

var teams = [{ id : 1, name : "LA"}, {id : 2, name: "IL"}]

const mergedList = players.map((player) => ({
  ...player,
  team: teams.find((team) => team.id === player.team),
}));

mergedList.forEach(ele => {
 console.log(`${ele.id}, ${ele.name} is in team ${ele.team.id}, ${ele.team.name}`);
});
```